# TimeStamp not working correctly, when changing Activity

Tags: java, android, timestamp

Im really new to Android programming(started yesterday) and im currently working on an App that should give me the time between first time clicking a button and second time clicking the button.

It works fine when i stay in the Activity. But if i change the activity while the time is "running" and then reenter the main activity it gives me a strange timestamp.

How the timestamp works:

I have a button for Start/Stop
On clicking start it calls a Method where i get the current system time in milliseconds and saves it to a variable.
On clicking stop it does the same and subtracts endTime-startTime. Thats how i get the total time.
(Works fine)

But when changing activity(I got a button where it changes to an activity where i can add a customer) and reentering main and stopping the timer, it adds the totalTime up to something i cant relate to.. currently my stop time is at 45 minutes.

Maybe i do something wrong on saving my values?

I'll just post my code. Maybe someone can help me and give me a hint. Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Class "Timerecording"

```
package com.example.cmsolutions.zeiterfassung;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class ZeitErfassen extends AppCompatActivity {

public static LinkedList<Kunde> kunden = new LinkedList();
boolean running = false;
long startTime,endTime,totalTime;
public Date date = new Date();

private SharedPreferences app_preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVAT=0;
private TextView displayTime;
public Button startEndButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zeit_erfassen);
    //Einstellungen laden
    app_preferences = getPreferences(PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVAT);
    displayTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zeit_bei_Kunde);
    startTime= app_preferences.getLong("startTime", 0);
    endTime = app_preferences.getLong("endTime", 0);
    running = app_preferences.getBoolean("running", false);
    totalTime = app_preferences.getLong("totalTime", 0);
    displayTime.setText((CharSequence) app_preferences.getString("zeitAnzeige", "Zeit bei Kunde"));
    startEndButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_Timer);
    startEndButton.setText((CharSequence)app_preferences.getString("timerButton","Start Timer"));
    editor = app_preferences.edit();
    editor.commit();

    createDropDown();

}


public void startTimer(View view) {



    if(running == false) {
        startTime = getTime();
        displayTime.setText("Zeitstoppung läuft");
        editor.putString("zeitAnzeige",(String)displayTime.getText());
        running = true;
        editor.putBoolean("running",true);
        editor.putLong("startTimer", startTime);
        startEndButton.setText("End Timer");
        editor.putString("timerButton", (String)startEndButton.getText());
        editor.commit();

    } else {
        endTime = getTime();
        editor.putLong("endTime",endTime);
        totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        editor.putLong("totalTime",totalTime);
        int hours   = (int) ((totalTime / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        int minutes = (int) ((totalTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
        int seconds = (int) (totalTime / 1000) % 60;
        displayTime.setText(String.valueOf(hours)+ ":"+String.valueOf(minutes)+":"+ String.valueOf(seconds));
        startEndButton.setText("Start Timer");
        editor.putString("timerButton",(String)startEndButton.getText());
        editor.commit();
        running = false;
    }
}

public void  neuerKunde(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddKunde.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public long getTime() {
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return millis;
}


public void createDropDown() {

    if(kunden.size() > 0) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.chooseCustomer);
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Kunde k:kunden) {
            names.add(k.getName());
        }
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

}

Class"AddCusomter"

```
    package com.example.cmsolutions.zeiterfassung;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class AddKunde extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_kunde2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}



public void addKunde(View view) throws Exception {
    try {
        EditText strings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerName);
        String name = strings.getText().toString();
        strings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressField);
        String address = strings.getText().toString();
        Kunde customer = new Kunde(name,address);
        ZeitErfassen.kunden.add(customer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Fehler in addKunde!");
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(this,ZeitErfassen.class));
}
```

}

I just realised, maybe its because at the end of method addKunde()  I start the MainActivity again?

PS: I think that I could also improve my Coding Style. If you have any Tips regarding better coding(methods to other class,....), im also greatuful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of start activity you can finish activity.

```
//startActivity(new Intent(this,ZeitErfassen.class));
finish();
```

Check the shared pref is XML is storing values using ddms.

Open shared prefs only when you need

```
  //OnCreate

  app_preferences =  getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
  Editor editor = pref.edit();

public void startTimer(View view) { 
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = = app_preferences.edit();
   if(running == false) { 
     startTime = getTime(); displayTime.setText("Zeitstoppung läuft");
     editor.putString("zeitAnzeige",(String)displayTime.getText()); 
     running = true; 
     editor.putBoolean("running",true); editor.putLong("startTimer", startTime);
     startEndButton.setText("End Timer");
     editor.putString("timerButton", (String)startEndButton.getText());
     editor.commit(); 
    } else { 
     endTime = getTime();
     editor.putLong("endTime",endTime); totalTime = endTime - startTime;
     editor.putLong("totalTime",totalTime);
     int hours = (int) ((totalTime / (1000*60*60)) % 24); int minutes = (int) ((totalTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
     int seconds = (int) (totalTime / 1000) % 60;
     displayTime.setText(String.valueOf(hours)+ ":"+String.valueOf(minutes)+":"+ String.valueOf(seconds));
     startEndButton.setText("Start Timer"); editor.putString("timerButton",(String)startEndButton.getText());
     editor.commit();
     running = false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! the finish() helped a lot!

Comment: If you satisfied please accept this answer and Mark it will help me to improve my self

Comment: But i still have a problem.... When it open the app under the button it shows me the text: Zeitstoppung läuft(Timecount running), though i didnt start it. What i want is that if i start the time and then end the app, it should show me "Zeitstoppung" läuft" so that i know that the time is running. Now, when it shows me that the time is running and i hit the startTimer button, it shows me a time of 20h:9m:13s.... I dont even know where this time comes from -.- Do i save wrong? Everytime i exit/close the app, i want to save all data(start,running, time and onCreate i want to reload it

Comment: so i can recalculate the current time if i hit stop... Do you know what i mean? ;-)

Comment: editor.putBoolean("running",false); in else statement ... You saved running status but didn't saved stop status